# MUI 5 - Autocomplete, ListboxComponent typescript issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm currently in the process of migrating some old MUI4 components to MUI5 components.

For the Autocomplete I have a variant that has some infinite loading with fetch logic.

In MUI4, the ListboxComponent was a `forwardRef` and it also supported extra props via `ListboxProps`. This works even now, the issues are in TS types, something changed here and I can't get a good solution for this. Both props face errors

Consider a minimal POC

```js
type ListBoxComponentProps = {
  someParam: boolean;
};

const ListboxComponent = forwardRef<
  HTMLUListElement,
  PropsWithChildren<ListBoxComponentProps>
>(({ children, someParam, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <List ref={ref} {...props}>
      {children}
    </List>
  );
});

<Autocomplete<DataObject>
  options={data}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tag}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    return (
      <ListItem {...props}>
        <Typography>{option.tag}</Typography>
        <Typography>{option.description}</Typography>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }}
  ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
  ListboxProps={{ someParam: true }}
/>
```

With the above code I get the following TS errors

- `ListboxComponent`
- `ListboxProps`

The errors are too long to copy paste here, but I do have a working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-listboxcomponent-zxx8k8?file=/src/App.tsx) example

Any help is much appreciated. I could not find one example of how to use these props in MUI5 with TS